# Explanation for log source sending truncated syslog

Tags: syslog

I'm attempting to send syslog from an authentication platform to a syslog server. The Authentication platform can only be configured to send syslog on UDP/514.

The log source is sending the events in a way I've not encountered before. I did a tcpdump and viewed the incoming data in wireshark. Wireshark sees a variety of syslog and what it identifies as RSH protocol. Events seem to be sent over the RSH protocol via TCP and a different source port. Then I see the event over UDP 514 on a different source port. This packet contains all the event data between two lines stating something like *****Event Occurrence Notification Start/END****. Then each piece of the previous log is sent again as a new packet.

My receiving syslog server doesn't know how to handle all this and I'm getting like 10 events for each event sent.

Wondering if there is any well known reason for something to send logs like this.

Thanks.

[image: Wireshark Example]

Comment: What does the TCP payload look like?, and, Where is the TCP connection being made? If data is being sent over TCP then something must be accepting the connection; is it from the platform to your syslog server, or something else?

Comment: Looking at the TCP traffic a bit closer. I'm not even sure it is TCP, might just be wireshark and tcpdump inocrrectly identifying it. Its a different source port but still dest port 514. No SYN/ACK/SYN-ACK flags or anything. it's coming from the log source to the syslog server

Comment: No, that's very unlikely – the IP header explicitly says whether the payload is TCP or UDP or something else. If Wireshark says it's TCP, then it's almost guaranteed to be TCP. On the other hand, the layer _above_ that (i.e. the TCP payload) can be easily misidentified as port numbers aren't set in stone – TCP port 514 used to be RSH back in the day, but these days it's actually far more likely to be "nonstandard" Syslog-over-TCP. (Which is why your syslog server is listening on that TCP port!) Right-click one of the TCP packets and select "Follow TCP stream" to see the entire data stream.

Comment: Still looking at it. Was a bit rusty in my wireshark. I did a capture for 15 minutes and all I see are ACK and ACK/PSH packets. No SYN or SYN-ACK. Going to run an even longer capture to see if I can see any SYNs. The log source documentation says it's not supposed to be even using TCP though. And that doesn't explain the odd fractured syslogs.